# Facing issues while connecting to website from Cyberark

Tags: cyber-ark

I am trying to connect to website by PSM with IE however its throwing error to me although same is working while connecting to PTA. Error : Error occured while while waiting for the display her to communicatie PSMSR606E

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your WebForm dispatcher is deprecated. You will need to use the WebApp Dispatcher. Once that's done, you should be able to work.
Thanks